# Eliminar un archivo en PHP usando su alias de .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

Tengo un código ***htaccess***, este renombra y da nombre *hola* al archivo `v.php` quedando:

```
www.example.com/hola
```

Entonces, yo quiero eliminar este "**v.php**", por su nombre *hola* (escrito por htaccess)

```
$e = __DIR__ . "/hola";
$result = unlink($e);
if ($result){
    echo "done";
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

Pero da este error:

```
Warning: unlink(C:\xampp\x\xxx_xxx/hola): No such file or directory in C:\xampp\x\xxx_xxx\delete.php on line 3
```

Pero necesito eliminarlo usando este rewrite de htaccess, pues saco la url de una base de datos.

¿Cómo puedo hacer?

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta. Si te da ese error es porque el fichero no existe, quizá ni siquiera el directorio existe. ¿Seguro que el fichero es renombrado como dices? ¿Cuando revisas en el árbol de directorios / archivos te aparece?

Comment: el archivo existe, solo que yo quiero eliminar un archivo usando su nombre reescrito por htaccess

Comment: @A.Cedano la cosa sería: eliminar un archivo por su "url limpia" creada en el **.htaccess**

Comment: Ohh, ahora sí se entiende que era lo que querías. Me alegro entonces de que lo hayas resuelto. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Conseguí la respuesta por mi mano.

Si tengo un elemento en `www.example.com/1.png` y renombrado como `www.example.com/imagenes/1`, usando un **str_replace**, bastaría

```
$one = __DIR__ . "/imagenes/1"; // variable del Rewrite por htaccess
$two = str_replace("imagenes/1", "1.png", $one); // remplazando por el lugar original
unlink($two); // y se elimina.
```

Y si quieres comprobar si se eliminó:

```
$r = unlink($two); // das una variable para la comprobación
if ($r){
    echo "done"; // se eliminó
} else {
    echo "fail"; // hubó un error
}
```

De esta manera puedes eliminar el archivo, sin desvelar la ubicación real del archivo al usuario *(en mi caso, quería esto)*